# Weatherproofing coax connections

Tags: connector, cables, humidity, environmental-sealing

I have coax-connectors connecting two cable runs that are subject to weather. Typically weatherproofing is done by wrapping the connection in suitable tape. This is a fairly messy solution if the connector needs to be opened.

I am wondering if somebody had an alternative solution. Are there weatherproof coax connectors for RG-58? A waterproof box to replace the tape maybe? Typical frequency: 150 MHz.

---

**Edit 1**

Somebody had added an answer about gel-filled boxes(?) but deleted it before I could read it. If the answer was at least marginally relevant, please consider adding it again. I would love to see an alternative to tape. Text of the missing answer:

> [Gel Splice Closures][1] Gel-filled box Ensures complete sealing of coaxial splices Watertight...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Water can get into boxes unless they have double O-ring water tight gaskets. There may be some around.

I prefer 3M Temflex™ 2155 Rubber Splicing Tape, but there is also  Scotch® Super 33+ which has a PVC backing for UV protection as an additional layer.

Carefully pry away with a pointed 1-edged razor knife to easily remove it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Richman. Why do you prefer "3M™ Temflex™ Rubber Splicing Tape 2155"? Have you tried "Scotch® Electrical Moisture Sealant" or "3M™ Tartan™ General Use Vinyl Electrical Insulating Tape 1710"?

Comment: Temflex is soft rubber that seals and standard electrical tape (Vinyl) does not have the same moisture sealing properties after heat cycles. Scotch® also works and has added PVC layer if you need UV protection. Depends on your budget and quantity required. THe Tartan may be adequate for room temp.

Comment: THe Tartan may be adequate with a lot of extra wraps... or with 10mil version and applied properly but harder to remove with thin PVC stretched tight.

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly, Scotch is a real alternative (i.e. like Temflex but UV resistant) but Tartan has significant downsides?

Comment: "Scotch Tartan" is a 3M trademark, but General Use Vinyl Electrical Tape 1710 is just one model of Vinyl or PVC adhesive film that has UV inhibitor properties.  TemFlex has better sealing properties being rubber. Both are better. and just PVC film only is messier to remove. Consult with 3m is advised.